# Laravel passport check if user is active before login

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth

I using **Guzzle** to send post request to passport `oauth/token` and here is the code:

```
public function login (Request $request) {
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {
        $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                'username' => $request -> email,
                'password' => $request -> password,
            ],
        ]);
        return $response->getBody();
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() === 400)
            return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
        else if ($e->getCode() === 401)
            return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
        else if ($e->getCode() === 408)
            return response()->json('User is deactivated. Please try again', $e->getCode());

        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

> What I am trying to do:

I have an active field for each user `1 is active and 0 is deactivated`.

I want to check before the user login if active or not and send a response with 408 code and message like i did in the if statement.

> What I have tried to do:

I have tried to add this to `User.php` model:

```
public function findForPassport($identifier) {
    return User::orWhere('email', $identifier)->where('active', 1)->first();
 }
```

It works fine.

> Problem is:

1) This return a response with 401 if not active and I want to return 408.

2) I don't know if this is the best way to do it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution by changing the **login function** code to this:

```
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    // CHECK IF EMAIL IS ACTIVE
    $active = User::where('email', $request -> email) -> where('active', 0) -> exists();
    if($active)
        return response()->json('This user is not active', 403);

    try {
        $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                'username' => $request -> email,
                'password' => $request -> password,
            ],
        ]);
        return $response->getBody();
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() === 400)
            return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
        else if ($e->getCode() === 401)
            return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
    }
```

This way I could simply check if the `user` is active or not using the `email`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you logging in using guzzle and not just the regular way? if you are just testing, use postman instead. Maybe have a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

But to answer your question, you can [modify this custom issueToken method](https://github.com/thunder87/laravel-snippets/blob/master/Passport/CustomAccessTokenController.php) and add the active check there. Also, [use this](https://github.com/thunder87/laravel-snippets/blob/master/Passport/PassportClientSecretProxy.php) passport client id/secret middleware "proxy", as the id/secret should not be visible to the public.

Comment: I am using Guzzle because I want to store the `client_id` and `client_secret` in the back-end instead of the front-end for security reasons.

Comment: Look at the answer, use the middleware «proxy» instead of the guzzle, that way you only need to pass the user credentials from the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

This  issue might help you [check here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/225)